# String parsing in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to parse a string in PHP:

```
 -father_name "John" -father_weight 44.50 
    -kid >name "Marko" >age 12
    -kid >name "Sevda" >age 17
    -kid >name "Nathan" >age 19
```

There are two main FORMS:

1. Attributes (such as -father, -weight, -kid)
2. Sub-Attributes (such as >name, >age)

**Note:** Attributes are NOT FIXED and NOT ALWAYS SEPERATED BY single space

And their VALUES have two types:

1. String (like "Marko")
2. Int or Decimal (like 12.00)

**OUTPUT would be:**

```
 $array['attributes'] = array('father_name ','father_weight ');
 $array['attributes']['kid'][] = array('name' => "Marko", 'age' => 12);
 $array['attributes']['kid'][] = array('name' => "Sevda", 'age' => 17);
 $array['attributes']['kid'][] = array('name' => "Nathan", 'age' => 19);
```

It should return **FORMS** (attrs and sub-attrs) and **VALUES** SEPARATELY.

How can I parse this line in **PHP** cleverly?

**Last Note:** Solution I found for this: YAML.

Comment: Can you give an example output?

Comment: where did the source file come from? ideally this type of file would have been created in xml, which would make it much easier to parse.

Comment: Is the input format unchangeable? There are similar formats with ready-made PHP parsers (like YAML)

Comment: Are attributes fixed or arbitrary?

Comment: Are the attributes always separated by a single space?  Multiple spaces? Tabs?

Comment: Attributes are NOT FIXED and NOT ALWAYS SEPERATED BY single space :(

Comment: but they are always separated from their values by a single space right?

Comment: What about the indenting? There is two spaces before -father and four for each kid. If that can vary how do we know kid is a subattribute of father. Also, why is weight not a subattribute of father? In other words, what constitutes a subgroup start and end?

Comment: And why are >name and >age keys while -father and -weight are values in the resulting array? What about John and 44.50?

Comment: @Gordon - First, I edited my first line like this: "-father_name "John" -father_weight 44.50"

Comment: Please update output array as well. Also, this doesnt answer my question about what constitutes beginning and end of subgroups. In addition, would this be possible `-kid >name "Marko" >age 12 -kid_weight 25`

Comment: @Gordon - I am thinking about what constitutes beginning and end of subgroups. But that code it's not possible. Because sub-attributes depends on only main attributes. it should be -kid >name "Marko" >age 12 >kid_weight 12.30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
function parse_attributes($string, $separators = array('-','>'), $level = 0){
    $attributes = explode($separators[$level], $string);
    $attrs = array();
    $ret_arr = array();
    foreach($attributes as $attribute){
        if(!empty($attribute)){
            $ex_attr = explode(' ',$attribute);
            if(!empty($ex_attr[1])){
                if(count($separators) > $level && strpos($attribute, $separators[$level+1])){
                    $ret = parse_attributes($attribute, $separators, $level+1);
                    array_push($ret_arr, $ret);
                }
                if (empty($ret_arr))
                    $attrs[$ex_attr[0]] = str_replace('"', '', $ex_attr[1]);
                else
                    $attrs[$ex_attr[0]] = $ret_arr;
            }
        }
    }
    return $attrs;
}
```

Using:

```
$returned = parse_attributes('-father_name "John" -father_weight 44.50 -kid >name "Marko" >age 12 -kid >name "Sevda" >age 17 -kid >name "Nathan" >age 19');

print_r($returned);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [father_name] => John
    [father_weight] => 44.50
    [kid] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Marko
                    [age] => 12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sevda
                    [age] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Nathan
                    [age] => 19
                )

        )

)
```

And using:

```
echo($returned['kid'][0]['name']);
```

Returns:

Marko

NOTE: You can specify more separator array items, an item for each attribute level you have.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
$input = explode('-', $input);
foreach ($input as $attribute) {
   $attribute = explode('>', $attribute);
   if (count($attribute) == 1) {
      $attribute = explode(' ', trim($sub_attribute), 2);
      $output[$attribute[0]] = eval($attribute[1]);
   } else {
      $attribute_name = trim($attribute[0]);
      if (!isset($output[$attribute_name]) {
         $output[$attribute_name] = array();
      }
      $sub_attribute_output = array();
      for ($i = 1; $i < count($attribute); $i++) {         
         $sub_attribute =  explode(' ', trim($attribute[$i]), 2);
         $sub_attribute_output[$sub_attribute[0]] = eval($sub_attribute[1]);
      }
      $output[$attribute_name][] = $sub_attribute_output;
   }
}
```

Comment: untested, but should work in all scenarios. let me know if it does not. the eval() handles the conversion to string, int, or float.

Comment: first there is a problem here     if (unset($output[$attribute_name]))

Comment: Eval for type conversion? That does sound evil!

Comment: @ThiefMaster What should we use for type conversation?

Comment: yeah changed unset to !isset. was writing fast to try to beat out other answers haha.

Comment: @dqhendricks - in this line $sub_attribute is array and should be string, i think for 'explode'. $sub_attribute =  explode(' ', trim($sub_attribute), 2);

Comment: @dino beytar good call. should be $sub_attribute = explode(' ', trim($attribute[$i]), 2);. edited to reflect fix. thanks!

Comment: @dqhendricks - It works well to get kid and its sub-attributes. I will improve it at my home. Thank all of you for helping.

Comment: by the way, i'm sure you already know, but if you use this, you will definitely want to replace the eval with some other form of type casting (for security reasons).